# Remove lines based on duplicate values

Tags: r, bash

I have a bash file with two fields.

eg:

```
ABC 0.23    
BCA 2.30    
AZS 1.23
CDA 2.11
XDS 0.45
ABC NA
CDA NA
ANG NA
```

There are two duplicates in the first column ABC and CDA. Both these duplicates will have NA in the second column. I want to remove those lines which have duplicates but remove the one which has NA in second while retaining all others.

Desired output:

```
ABC 0.23
BCA 2.30
AZS 1.23
CDA 2.11    
XDS 0.45
ANG NA
```

I tried R but the output is messy. I hope there is a better way in bash for a file with around 40000 lines.

Thanks!

Comment: In R this seems like `df[!duplicated(df$V1),]` where `V1` is the name of the first column

Comment: No. NAs are actual values. No line is blank

Comment: No there is no blank line in between. I apologize for putting it up that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution using `awk`:

```
awk '( !($1 in val) || $2 != "NA" ) { val[$1] = $2 } 
     END { for (k in val) { print k" "val[k] } }'
```

Output:

```
CDA 2.11
ABC 0.23
AZS 1.23
ANG NA
XDS 0.45
BCA 2.30
```

If you need to preserve the order of the lines, that will require more work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `unique` from `data.table` in R

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(df)[order(is.na(Col2))], by='Col1')
#   Col1 Col2
#1:  ABC 0.23
#2:  BCA 2.30
#3:  AZS 1.23
#4:  CDA 2.11
#5:  XDS 0.45
#6:  ANG   NA
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Col1 = c("ABC", "BCA", "AZS", "CDA", "XDS", "ABC", 
"CDA", "ANG"), Col2 = c(0.23, 2.3, 1.23, 2.11, 0.45, NA, NA, 
NA)), .Names = c("Col1", "Col2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```